# Need suggestion for framework

Tags: php, frameworks, oauth, facebook-graph-api, twitter-oauth

I just went through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648/what-php-framework-would-you-choose-for-a-new-application-and-why discussion and read about frameworks.

Till now I've been coding from scratch everytime I developer a new application, Now I want to start with a framework for new project. Things I am looking for in the framework

1. User Signup Process OAuth module for
2. List item Twitter (fetching tweets) (**important**)
3. OAuth module for Facebook (fetching wall-posts) (**important**)
4. MVC Architecture
5. Paypal module for payments

I dont know if such framework exists, and I am new to frameworks, so I am looking for suggestion for which framework to start with and what all modules/plugins to pick

- Language: PHP
- Backend: MySQL
- Frontend: HTML5/CSS
- Platform: OSX

Comment: That sounds like a lot of very specific stuff for a *framework*

Comment: Remind, that you always can combine multiple frameworks and libraries. For example you can use Zend Framework for your application (MVC) and additional a specialised PayPal-library

Comment: @David. I wanted to know framework which would have these plugins.. I was viewing framework something similar to a cms, guess was wrong..

Comment: @kingCrunch, thanks! will give Zend a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just a framework for a solid base and the create those things as models. 
I think most frameworks offer something for authentication don't know about the rest, but as I said, use a framework for base and then build what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most solid php framework "base" you can use is ZEND. Then, as already said, you can easily add features/plugins! :)

Answer (score 0):

The most happening future proof, nimble framework in php at the moment I believe in Lithium checkout [it out here](http://lithify.me)

I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

For small projects: http://alloyframework.org/

For medium / experimental: gotta be http://li3.me/

for large projects: Zend - just so flexible. CAVEAT - Zend Form Decorators are an utter horror. Sorry guys...